# Neo4j Database : ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure

Tags: neo4j

I am new in working with Neo4jDatabase. I am getting the following error as I ran this query :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
 'file:///Test.csv' AS line 
 WITH line
 CREATE (terminal:Terminal {id:TOINT(line.TERMINAL_ID)});
```

[image]

I am running Neo4j on local Windows.

Comment: *"the following error"* - what error do you get?

Comment: Guessing that picture was the following error... but you should include that as text, so that someone else googling the error can find your question

Comment: ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3 on windows

Answer (score -1):

**You are not connected to the database.**

You need to do `:server connect` to establish your connection. Type that into the query box and follow the prompt to input your credentials before attempting other queries.

The web interface only provides a way to interact with your database. It's a full client-side web application that serves as a front-end for the operations you perform.

Behind the scenes, it uses a Bolt connection in a WebSocket to actually talk to your database. Accessing the website does not automatically establish this connection (although typically you are given a prompt to do so as soon as you access the web UI). If you ever get disconnected while using the web UI (as appears to be the case here), the socket must be re-opened with `:server connect`.

Comment: First, I established the connection than I run the query. But as I execute the transaction. I am getting this error.